# E: The package lxc-stuff needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: python-3.x, debian, lxc

I'm using Debian Wheezy as a development environment for my LXC project using python, the Stable Debian repos doesn't have LXC 1.0.x so I had to get from Jessie's repos it did't work well for me as I got my apt-get stuck at:

```
E: The package lxc-stuff needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq lxc-stuff
```